# Update nuget package with option -IgnoreDependencies get error

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I could not update the `WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet Package with the option `-IgnoreDependencies`. When I update it with following command in the Package Manager Console, I always get the error:

```
update-package WindowsAzure.Storage -IgnoreDependencies
```

The error:

```
Update-Package : packages
At line:1 char:15
+ update-package <<<<  WindowsAzure.Storage -IgnoreDependencies
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

Now my workaround is uninstall that package, then install it with the option -IgnoreDependencies. But I have a lot of projects and I need update it frequently. So I want to know the best way to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Update nuget package with option -IgnoreDependencies get error

I can reproduce this issue on one computer, but I can not reproduce it on another computer. I compared all the differences between them, the final finding is the **NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio version of the difference** when you update the nuget package `WindowsAzure.Storage` with option `-IgnoreDependencies`.

The version of NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio on the computer which have the issue is `3.4.4.1321`, the version on another one is `3.5.0.1996`. So to resolve this issue, please update the nuget package manager to the 3.5.0.1996:

Uninstall the 3.4.4 from Tools->Extensions and Updates->NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio. Restart the Visual Studio. Then install the 3.5.0.1996 from [nuget.org](https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/v3.5.0/NuGet.Tools.vsix), restart the Visual Studio.

Note: This issue only occurred when you update the nuget package `WindowsAzure.Storage` from `4.3.0` with `-IgnoreDependencies` option.